# IP address lookup with appended port

Tags: dns

I'm trying to setup a lan info webserver for casual users - as in I need to keep it simple. My router is a netgear wnr2000 running ddwrt with dnsmasq setup to provide local DNS. My webserver is a cheap android box running PAWS http server. Currently, users have to type "my house:8080/page name" as the Url. This is a step up from having to input the full IP address but I'd like to eliminate the port reference.  Not entirely sure how to do this particularly since my only computing resources on the network are the router and android box. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the need for port reference when users want to access your "my house" URL you should use port 80 (default http port) and not port 8080.

Had a little Google and found this article about getting PAW to listen on Port 80 by changing the iptables
http://fun2code-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/running-paw-on-port-80.html

code from the link is below ( I haven't tested so use at your own discretion), you need to be root user

```
import de.fun2code.android.pawserver.util.*;

execRootShell(String[] commands) {
  shellCmd = "su -c sh";

  sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCmd);
  os = sh.getOutputStream();

  for(cmd : commands) {
    os.write((cmd + "\n").getBytes());
  }

  os.write(("exit\n").getBytes());
  os.flush();
  sh.waitFor(); 
}

/* ---- Config -------- */
ip = Utils.getLocalIpAddress();
redirectFrom = 80;
redirectTo = 8080;
action = "ADD"; // Can be ADD or DELETE
/* -------------------- */

action = "-" + action.substring(0, 1);

String[] iptablesCmds = new String[] {
  "iptables -t nat " + action + " OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport " + redirectFrom + " -j REDIRECT --to-ports " + redirectTo,
  "iptables -t nat " + action + " OUTPUT -d " + ip + " -p tcp --dport " + redirectFrom + " -j REDIRECT --to-ports " + redirectTo,
  "iptables -t nat " + action + " PREROUTING -d " + ip + " -p tcp --dport " + redirectFrom + " -j REDIRECT --to-ports " + redirectTo
};

execRootShell(iptablesCmds);
```